# Java midi program selection strange behaviour

Tags: java, midi

I've tried to find any information regarding this but I haven't been able to find anything that helps.

I'm trying to make a program that generates a midi-file consisting of two instruments playing at once using different instruments(programs) on them. I have been using a sample program:
http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs211/2008sp/examples/MidiSynth.java.txt
as a template but when I try and create the midi events artificially(as opposed to generating them on the fly with the synth in the sample program), the resulting midi-file doesn't seem to care that I have switched programs, using the last changed-to program for every note in the file, consisting of two midi-tracks, even though I have saved program-change data to both tracks. I have pasted the code for my program beneith:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.midi.Sequence;
import javax.sound.midi.Soundbank;
import javax.sound.midi.Sequencer;
import javax.sound.midi.Synthesizer;
import javax.sound.midi.Instrument;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiChannel;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiEvent;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiMessage;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem;
import javax.sound.midi.ShortMessage;
import javax.sound.midi.Track;
import javax.sound.midi.InvalidMidiDataException;    

public class MidiTest2
{
    /*  This velocity is used for all notes.
     */
    private static final int    VELOCITY = 64;
        final int PROGRAM = 192;
        final int NOTEON = 144;
        final int NOTEOFF = 128;

        long startTime;
        Sequence sequence;
        Synthesizer synthesizer;
        Sequencer sequencer;
        Instrument instruments[];
        ChannelData channels[];
        ChannelData cc;
        //int instrumentCounter = 0;

        Track track;

        MidiTest2(){
            try{
               if(synthesizer == null){
                   if((synthesizer = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer()) == null){
                       System.out.println("getSynthesizer() failed");
                       return;
                   }
               }
               synthesizer.open();
               sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
               sequence = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 10);

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            Soundbank sb = synthesizer.getDefaultSoundbank();
            if(sb != null){
                instruments = synthesizer.getDefaultSoundbank().getInstruments();
                synthesizer.loadInstrument(instruments[0]);
            }

            MidiChannel midiChannels[] = synthesizer.getChannels();
            channels = new ChannelData[midiChannels.length];

            for(int i = 0; i < channels.length;++i){
                channels[i] = new ChannelData(midiChannels[i], i);
            }

            cc = channels[0];

        }

        public void createShortEvent(int type, int num){
            ShortMessage message = new ShortMessage();
            try{
                long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                long tick = millis * sequence.getResolution() / 500;
                message.setMessage(type+cc.num, num, cc.velocity);
                System.out.println("Type: " + message.getCommand() + ", Data1: " + message.getData1() + ", Data2: " + message.getData2() + ", Tick: " + tick);

                MidiEvent event = new MidiEvent(message, tick);
                track.add(event);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void createShortEvent(int type, int num, int eventTime){
            ShortMessage message = new ShortMessage();
            try{
                //long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                long tick = eventTime * sequence.getResolution();
                    message.setMessage(type+cc.num, num, cc.velocity);

                System.out.println("Type: " + message.getCommand() + ", Data1: " + message.getData1() + ", Data2: " + message.getData2() + ", Tick: " + tick);

                MidiEvent event = new MidiEvent(message, tick);
                track.add(event);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void saveMidiFile(){
            try {
                int[] fileTypes = MidiSystem.getMidiFileTypes(sequence);
                if (fileTypes.length == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Can't save sequence");
                } else {
                    if (MidiSystem.write(sequence, fileTypes[0], new File("testmidi.mid")) == -1) {
                        throw new IOException("Problems writing to file");
                    } 
                }
            } catch (SecurityException ex) { 

            } catch (Exception ex) { 
                ex.printStackTrace(); 
            }
        }

        void run(){
            //System.out.println("sequence: " + sequence.getTracks().length);
            createNewTrack(0);
            createShortEvent(NOTEON, 60, 2);
            createShortEvent(NOTEOFF, 60, 3);
            createShortEvent(NOTEON, 61, 3);
            createShortEvent(NOTEOFF, 61, 4);
            createShortEvent(NOTEON, 62, 4);
            createShortEvent(NOTEOFF, 62, 5);
            createShortEvent(NOTEON, 63, 5);
            createShortEvent(NOTEOFF, 63, 6);

            createNewTrack(5);

            createShortEvent(NOTEON, 50, 1);
            createShortEvent(NOTEOFF, 50, 5);

            playMidiFile();
            saveMidiFile();
        }

        void printTrack(int num){
            Track tempTrack = sequence.getTracks()[num];
            System.out.println(tempTrack.get(0).getTick());
        }

        void playMidiFile(){
            try{
                sequencer.open();
                sequencer.setSequence(sequence);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sequencer.start();
        }

        void createNewTrack(int program){
            track = sequence.createTrack();
            programChange(program);
        }

        void programChange(int program){

            cc.channel.programChange(program);
            System.out.println("program: " + program);
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            createShortEvent(PROGRAM, program);
        }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            MidiTest2 mt = new MidiTest2();
            mt.run();                
    }

}
```

The ChannelData-class(that doesn't do anything but I thought I'd post it for completeness sake):

```
public class ChannelData {
    MidiChannel channel;
    boolean solo, mono, mute, sustain;
    int velocity, pressure, bend, reverb;
    int row, col, num;

    public ChannelData(MidiChannel channel, int num) {
        this.channel = channel;
        this.num = num;
        velocity = pressure = bend = reverb = 64;
    }

    public void setComponentStates() {

    }

}
```

In the program I try to create 5 notes with the acoustic piano-sound and one note with an electric piano sound. However all notes are played back with the electric piano sound even though I create a new track before I switch instrument.

I have been trying to figure this out now for 5 hours or something and I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: "I thought I'd post it for completeness sake" If it's not relevant, don't post it. Similarly, does this only happen with 5 notes, or does it happen with just 1? http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve I'm not trying to be obstinate, just there is a lot of code here to wade through.

Comment: Yeah, I understand your point. What I meant was to make it easier for anyone trying to just get the code running in which case I thought it would be better if it was complete. I got it working though and it turned out the code that I thought didn't matter actually did. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracks can help your own program with organizing events, but they do not affect the synthesizer in any way.

To be able have different settings, you must use different channels.

Comment: I seemed not to grasp the difference between midi-tracks and midi-channels. For anyone else that could have the same problem, what solved it is that when sending the midi-message, I hade to add the channel-number to the message-command type, that is a program change for channel 3 is 192 + 3. When I did that before the program change and of course for all notes that should go on that channel, everything worked. Thank you!